# how to get multipleOutput in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, outputformat

I'm new to Hadoop, and now have to process a input file. I want to process each line and the output should be one file for each line.

I surf the internet and found MultipleOutputFormat, and generateFileNameForKeyValue.

But most people write it with JobConf class. As I'm using Hadoop 0.20.1, I think Job class takes place. And I don't know how to use Job class to generate multiple output files by key.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you fixed to your version of Hadoop? 0.20.1 doesn't have a ported version of MultipleOutput for the new mapreduce api package. If possible, upgrade to the latest 1.x version?

Comment: I'm using hadoop eclipse plugin 0.20.1. I don't know there is 1/x version. Could you give me the address for 1.x?

Comment: What is your target cluster running (or are you using Eclipse to run in Local mode?)

Comment: Yes, I just want to try it locally, and I inserted a hadoop-0.20.1-eclipse-plugin.jar to my eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse plugin is mainly used to submit and monitor jobs as well as interact with HDFS, against a real or 'psuedo' cluster.

If you're running in local mode, then i don't think the plugin gains you anything - seeing as your job will be run in a single JVM. With this in mind i would say include include the most recent 1.x hadoop-core in your Eclipse project's classpath.

Eitherway `MultipleOutputFormat` has not been ported to the new mapreduce package (neither in 1.1.2 or 2.0.4-alpha), so you'll either need to port it yourself or find another way (maybe `MultipleOutputs` - The [Javadoc page has some usage on using MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html))